# Как разрабатывать через связку PhpStorm + Docker?

Tags: php, windows, phpstorm, docker

В интернете куча информации о докере по базовым вещам, таких как "как скачать образ", "как запустить контейнер", но почти ничего нет о том, что дальше с этим делать. Как, собственно, разрабатывать-то?

К примеру, сделал я `pull` дистрибутива  [linode/lamp](https://hub.docker.com/r/linode/lamp/), у него в папке `/var/www/example.com/public_html/` лежит проект. 
Запускаю: `docker run -p 80:80 -t -i linode/lamp /bin/bash`, `service apache2 start`. Теперь в браузере по адресу `http://localhost` вижу индексную страницу того проекта.

Окей. Теперь я хочу редактировать/добавлять/удалять файлы в этом проекте. Делать это через bash и редактор nano - не совсем здравая идея, очевидно. Поэтому я хочу это делать в *PhpStorm*. И тут я уже не понимаю, что делать.
Какой пункт выбирать при создании проекта?

- Web server is installed locally, source files are located under its document root.
- Web server is installed locally, source files are located elsewhere locally.
- Web server is on a remote host, files are accessible via network share or mounted drive.
- Web server is on a remote host, files are accessible via FTP/SFTP/FTPS.
- Source files are in a local directory, no Web server is yet configured.

Если первый, то где брать файлы, если через FTP/SFTP/FTPS, то как настраивать? Я не понимаю.

Я знаю, что в *PhpStorm* можно настроить *Deployment - Docker* и его конфигурацию. Вот как у меня выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но это дает возможность лишь запускать контейнеры *Docker* и обращаться к ним, например через ту же консоль. Может быть нужно использовать это как-то?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем я не понимаю. У меня каша в голове уже. Объясните пожалуйста. Хотелось бы видеть ответ для *Windows* и *Linux* (если есть разница, конечно)

P.S. Я использую *Docker* на *Windows* - в настройках переключенный на *Linux* (Switched to linux)

Comment: Сама по себе данная возможность в IDEA пока не реализована, но вы можете проголосовать за ее [реализацию](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-337588/Add-ability-to-add-edit-delete-files-in-Docker-Container-directly-from-IDE-add-Docker-to-Deployment-connection-types)

Answer (score 2):

Все манипуляции надо производить через сам **docker**.

1 Найдите подходящий вам образ для работы с PHP

2 При запуске контейнера примонтируйте папку с вашим проектом в */var/www/*

```
docker run -v /path/to/project/:/var/www -td IMAGE_NAME
```

(Все параметры на ваше усмотрение, можете запускать -it если нужно работать в контейнере)

[-v](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems): Монтирование volume с хоста в контейнер.

-d: Запуск в бэкграду

-t: Что бы при запуске он не выключался.

IMAGE_NAME: Имя образа

Открываете ваш проект который находиться в `/path/to/project/` через **PhpStorm** и можете свободно работать.

Comment: Нет, "-v" - это чтобы приаттачить папку с винды в докер, а, по-сути, нужно наоборот. Ведь Если так сделать, то папка из винды затрёт ту, что в контейнере. Представляете, работодатель даёт образ с проектом, я туда вставляю свою папку и она умирает) Да, можно создать в контейнере отдельно папку например "projects", скинуть туда данные из "/var/www" , потом прикрепить "volume" и потом обратно кинуть файлы, но разве это не извращение? Или с докером по-другому не работают?))

Comment: @Михаил Наоборот это не делается. Нельзя прикрепить volume с контейнера на хост (при помощи CLI докерка). В чем проблема зайти на контейнер, кинуть проект в другую директорию, примонтировать volume, кинуть обратно проект? дело на 2 минуты.

Comment: "Нельзя прикрепить volume с контейнера на хост (при помощи CLI докерка)." - есть же docker-compose, в котором, на сколько я смог понять, автоматом прокидывается сеть между хостом и контейнерами. Разве просто в docker невозможно в итоге также прокинуть сеть? Это же просто образ линухи. А кинуть проект в другую директорию,  а потом обратно, как я писал - это большой изврат (Но если это единственный путь...).  К тому же что делать, если я хочу прикрутить npm плагины и не только для работы, зачем мне структуру контейнера трогать портить?  А для работы с СУБД из хоста тоже надо танцевать с бубном ?

Answer (score 0):

Сама по себе данная возможность в IDEA пока не реализована, но вы можете проголосовать за ее реализацию ( [тикет1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-337588/Add-ability-to-add-edit-delete-files-in-Docker-Container-directly-from-IDE-add-Docker-to-Deployment-connection-types) | [тикет2](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-330529/Cant-edit-files-running-in-docker-containers) )

Обходной путь:
Можно установить на контейнер ssh-сервер и через него сделать SFTP-подключение. Но только контейнер этот для начала нужно будет перезапустить (а точнее, пересоздать) в привилегированном режиме (что нужно делать с осторожностью, лучше почитать документацию об этом), и пробросить ssh-порт:
`docker run -p 2222:22 --privileged {Image ID} /usr/sbin/init`
 (источник - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50438053, если не указать `--privileged` и `/usr/sbin/init`, то будет ошибка Failed to get D-Bus connection).
Если переразворачивать контейнер не из командной строки, а из интерфейса phpstorm, то выглядеть это будет примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После установки ssh-cервера на контейнер, к нему можно будет подключиться. Только не забыть его предварительно запустить - `systemctl restart sshd` либо `service sshd restart`. Вот пример подключения из командной строки, если контейнер развернут локально:
`ssh username@localhost -p 2222`
Можно конечно при разворачивании контейнера указать не 2222 (либо любой другой) порт, а 22, и тогда при подключении ssh порт вообще не нужно будет указывать, но тогда нужно будет иметь ввиду, что порт по умолчанию уже занят данным контейнером

По хорошему SFTP должен идти в комплекте с SSH (по крайней мере в моем случае это было так, пробовал на centos), так что после его установки можно приступать к настраиванию подключения из Phpstorm:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и пользоваться уже привычным SFTP. Но опять же повторюсь, нужно быть осторожным с привилегированными контейнерами, так как например в отличие от обычных они могут иметь [root-доступ к машине-хосту](https://habr.com/ru/companies/otus/articles/513102/). А во вторых, в докере принято разносить все сервисы по разным контейнерам в рамках одного docker-compose, а ssh это тоже сервис. Так что подобное решение с ssh/sftp может посчитаться плохим тоном. Но пока что действительно непонятно, какой есть еще более удобный способ закидывать файлы в контейнер